# Read data from Json when passing from view to controller in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a problem when i passing data from view to controller in laravel 5
In controller, i receive is:

```
array(2) {
  ["usercode"]=>
  string(72) "
                                SK20160005
                            "
  ["password"]=>
  string(70) "
                                oepyjrhy
                            "
}
```

i have try to read data from it, but not success.
Someone can help me.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Use ajax load data. I don't understand why not suscess

Comment: did you tried something like this?  $data = $request->all();  dd($data['usercode']); check if this works,  but usualy you have to do this $usercode = $request->input('usercode');  $pwd = $request->input('password');

Comment: I have use json_decode(var_dump($_POST), true); to get object have data is it.
then, i can't get data for each key is password or username?

Comment: Try : $user= $_POST[2]["usercode"];  and $password= $_POST[2]["password"];

Comment: can't use it, it return NULL;

Comment: First of all, are you trying to pass data from **Controller to View** or from **View to Controller**? Also, can you paste your full code (like the whole function). We might be able to understand your problem properly then.